# Batch File Skipping over FOR LOOP

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

***UPDATE***
I removed the tokens=4 and it started outputting data.  It is not skipping past the FOR LOOP.  I was skipping too far ahead with the tokens.  I am still a little confused as to why it works as a single batch and not from this batch but now at least I know what the issue was.  Thank you to everyone that was looking into this for me.

I am writing a script to copy over data from one computer to another.  The issue is that it is skipping over the FOR LOOP that I am calling from another FOR LOOP. If you are testing the script it requires two PC's and a mapped T: drive to somewhere on the second computer.  I can write the script so it looks for an external drive if that is more helpful to someone.

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 skip=1" %%a in ('REG QUERY "%_regshell%" /v "%_regdesktop%"') DO (
     SET _dt=%%a
     echo robocopy "!_dt!" "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!" !_params!
     echo attrib -h -r "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!"
    )
```

If I write the FOR LOOP above in a batch by itself and just echo out %%a then it works without a problem.  In this, I can see that it is indeed calling  :_backup but it skips directly over the FOR Loop and I am not sure why.  I have written scripts like this many times but never had any that just completely ignore the FOR Loop.  Can anyone take a look and assist?  Thank you.

```
@echo off
:: Set Variables
SET _driveID=T:
SET _params=/Z /E /COPY:DT /R:1 /W:0 /XD LocalService NetworkService temp "temporary internet files" winsxs Content.IE5 cache /XF ntuser.* *.tmp /XJ /FP /NC /NS /NP /NJH
SET _regshell=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
SET _regdesktop=Desktop

:: Set Current Directory
pushd %SystemDrive%\

:: Start Menu - Create Choices and Options.  Send to various places to perform the actions.
:_start
cls
ECHO   Please type either option 2 or 3 and then press ENTER on the keyboard?
Echo     2. TRANSFER FILES FROM DESKTOP TO LAPTOP
Echo     3. EXIT THE PROGRAM
echo.
set /p choice=Enter Number: 

if '%choice%'=='2' goto _desktopToLaptop
if '%choice%'=='3' goto :EOF
echo "%choice%" is not a valid option.  Please try again
echo.
goto _start

:: Detect Drive Letters
:_desktopToLaptop
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%a IN (`WMIC logicaldisk where DeviceID^="%_driveID%" get caption`) DO (
    SET _NetworkDrive=%%a
    if exist %%a ( 
      CALL :_backup
      goto :EOF
    ) else (
      echo.
      echo The laptop does not appear to be attached to the computer.
      echo.
      pause
      goto :EOF
    )
)

:_backup
:: Detect the folder locations and begin to backup each location to the laptop.
FOR /F "tokens=4 skip=1" %%a in ('REG QUERY "%_regshell%" /v "%_regdesktop%"') DO (
 SET _dt=%%a
 echo robocopy "!_dt!" "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!" !_params!
 echo attrib -h -r "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!"
)
echo we are past the for loop
pause
:: Return to directory program was run from
popd
```

Comment: Perhaps using different `metavariables` for the two loops may advance your cause. You are using `%%a` for both.

Comment: The `PUSHD` will never execute.

Comment: Please see  [mcve]. Posting dozens and dozens of lines of code isn't necessary.

Comment: @Magoo: I did try %%b and %%c and it doesn't get that far.

Comment: @Squashman: Why is that?  I believe it is in the system drive C: when this executes.  I can check the CD though to be sure.  Nevermind, I see it.  Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: I have come to know in StackOverflow there is someone that is not happy no matter what I do.  I have read and followed those rules and if you look at my other posts that DO follow those rules they get marked down by people that tell me that I don't have enough code.  When I add the code necessary I get people that tell me I have too much code.

Comment: If you read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as I suggested, you'll be able to find a good balance between *not enough code* and *a huge dump of largely irrelevant code*. Expecting us to wade through lots of code that has nothing to do with the problem isn't reasonable.

Comment: @KenWhite: If you look at the code, there is not a lot.  There are 2 FOR LOOPS, the START MENU that are necessary to test the program and the rest is variables.  I can remove the variables I haven't utilized yet if you would like.

Comment: The vast majority of the initial  SET statements, the menu, and the majority (if not all) of the lines below the FOR loops are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @KenWhite: I removed all unnecessary SET Variables and removed all echo statements as well as the number 1 choice which was not relevant.  Everything else in there is needed for the program to run, along with a mapped drive to another computer named T:.  I'll edit the text to state the requirement for the script to run.

Comment: Much better. :-) Thanks for listening. You'll find that if you follow that advice for your questions here in the future, you'll have a much more pleasant experience.

Comment: I just figured something out.  I removed the tokens and the skip and it started outputting data.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue or something similar, check your tokens and your skip.  Mine worked just fine as a single batch but when I included as a call I had to change the options from tokens=4 skip=1 to tokens=3* skip=2 in order to get the correct output.

The correct tokens in that FOR LOOPS should be:

```
@echo off
:: Set Variables
SET _driveID=T:
SET _params=/Z /E /COPY:DT /R:1 /W:0 /XD LocalService NetworkService temp "temporary internet files" winsxs Content.IE5 cache /XF ntuser.* *.tmp /XJ /FP /NC /NS /NP /NJH
SET _regshell=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
SET _regdesktop=Desktop

:: Set Current Directory
pushd %SystemDrive%\

:: Start Menu - Create Choices and Options.  Send to various places to perform the actions.
:_start
cls
ECHO   Please type either option 2 or 3 and then press ENTER on the keyboard?
Echo     2. TRANSFER FILES FROM DESKTOP TO LAPTOP
Echo     3. EXIT THE PROGRAM
echo.
set /p choice=Enter Number: 

if '%choice%'=='2' goto _desktopToLaptop
if '%choice%'=='3' goto :EOF
echo "%choice%" is not a valid option.  Please try again
echo.
goto _start

:: Detect Drive Letters
:_desktopToLaptop
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%a IN (`WMIC logicaldisk where DeviceID^="%_driveID%" get caption`) DO (
    SET _NetworkDrive=%%a
    if exist %%a ( 
      CALL :_backup
      goto :EOF
    ) else (
      echo.
      echo The laptop does not appear to be attached to the computer.
      echo.
      pause
      goto :EOF
    )
)

:_backup
:: Detect the folder locations and begin to backup each location to the laptop.
FOR /F "tokens=3* skip=2" %%a in ('REG QUERY "%_regshell%" /v "%_regdesktop%"') DO (
 SET _dt=%%a
 echo robocopy "!_dt!" "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!" !_params!
 echo attrib -h -r "!_NetworkDrive!\!_fndesktop!"
)
echo we are past the for loop
pause
:: Return to directory program was run from
popd
```

Comment: There appears to be at least one variable, `!_fndesktop!`, which is not defined anywhere in your script.

Comment: @Compo: At the request Ken White, I removed all unnecessary items that didn't pertain to the question and must have forgotten about that one.  What you are seeing is not the full script due to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the main issue in your script appears to be the setting of a variable to the data within the defined registry key and value, you could use:

```bat
Set "_regshell=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
Set "_regdesktop=Desktop"

Set "_dt="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%_regshell%" /V "%_regdesktop%"'
) Do Set "_dt=%%~B"
If Not Defined _dt GoTo :EOF
Echo "%_dt%"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to try this and see if it works better.  I actually did get my script to read data when I removed the tokens from the FOR Loop however I am going to try this and see if this works better.  What does the EOL=H do?

Comment: @scrfix, it ignores any lines which begin with `H`, i.e. the Registry Key, `HK…`. This means that only one line will be passed to a metavariable, the one containing the data we need. _We know that because we know that line will begin with `Desktop`, because I haven't set any delimiters, the default space character will be ignored up to that `D`_.